# how to make children img tag clickable along with parent div?

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I have used slick lightbox on ul element class .slider-lightbox. Everything is working fine while clicking on li but on the first li I have added a play-btn class in the center using position which is not clickable but the outer part works on click. So how should I make the .play-btn class clickable along with its li? Thank you.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider-lightbox').slickLightbox({
        navigateByKeyboard: true
    });

   $('.video .play-btn').click(function() {
       $('.video .play-btn').closest('.video').trigger("click");
       return false;
   })
 })
```

```html
<ul class="slider-lightbox">
 <li class="video active">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/g_192AvTJcM" width="400px" target="_blank">
   <img src="images/community/img2.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <img class="play-btn" src="images/video-icon.png">
 </li>
 <li class="image active">
  <a href="images/community/img3.jpg" target="_blank">
   <img src="images/community/img3.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
 </li>
 <li class="image active">
      <a href="images/community/img1.jpg" target="_blank">
       <img src="images/community/img1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Whatever you want execute on "Play button" you can still code it on "li" too. Is there any specific reason you want both of them clickable separately?

Comment: I am using slicklightbox plugin due to which if I click on children of ul slicklightbox works but the play-btn is not clickable. I want the play-btn should also works that's why i have use that code to make it clickable but doesn't work